# JQuery drop-down list selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm kind of new with JQuery, so this is what I'm trying to do: here I'm creating a drop-down menu when clicking on the icon (called 'otherActions').

If the user selects the first I want it do do something (like reset password). If the second one is selected I want it to do something else.

How can I do this using JQuery? I don't know where the methods should be placed. Thank you so much for the help!

```
var otherActions = $('<div class="icon" style="...." title="..."></div>');
$(otherActions).click(function()
{
    var menuDiv = $('#otherActions');
    if (menuDiv.length == 0)
    {
        menuDiv = $('<div id="otherActions" class="myObject" style="..."></div>');
        $('body').append(menuDiv);
    }
    otherActions = new myObject(menuDiv);  
    otherActions.addItem('Action 1', 0);      //myObject methods 
    otherActions.addItem('Action 2', 1);
    otherActions.popupXY(x, y);            //myObject method that creates the drop-down list
});
result.append(otherActions); // this is just one of the icons I have to set up
```

Comment: You could use the change event which jquery provides on t the drop down box get the value of the selected option, and switch on that to do your respective actions

Comment: This is what I wand to do. But this is the code I have to work on, and in this case, being new to jquery, I could use some help to use it properly

Comment: I posted an answer. Maybe itll help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery's [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/). This will be triggered when you change a value in the drop down menu. Usage would be something like this :

```
$("select").change(
 function () {
  var val=this.value;
  switch (val)
  {
    case "reset" :
     //do action for reset
     break;
    case "someother" :
     //do something else
     break;
   }
)
```

**Note**
You'll have to put this code after you `append` the drop down into your html. Your drop down must exist in the DOM for this event to get attached to the dropdown. For note info on this, see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: But I have <div> elements.. What should be my selector? $("??").change

Comment: But didn't you say you have a drop down menu?